# Make a single keystroke shortcut for Command+Tab to switch applications?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, application-switcher

I'd like to use a single keystroke to invoke the Application Switcher (<kbd>Command+Tab</kbd>). How can I do this?

Comment: An example or 3 would be helpful, and, generally, universal shortcuts like COMMAND-Tab require (from a practical perspective) a Key/Modifier combination like for example... err... COMMAND-Tab...

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/548146/change-command-tab-to-option-tab-on-mac

Comment: Which key do you want to use for the "single keystroke"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had great success with [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) for remapping keyboard keys to do different things. I haven't tested it with this exact use case but it can probably be done.

[BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) is a powerful utility that allows you to assign shortcuts to essentially anything on any input device for mac. If Karabiner Elements can't do this for you, BetterTouchTool can.

I use both of these programs and have yet to find a shortcut or remapping that I've wanted to do which I haven't been able to with these programs.